# Delphi: All constants are constant, but some are more constant than others?

Tags: delphi, constants, compiler-errors, delphi-5, compile-time-constant

Consider:

```
const 
   clHotlight: TColor = $00FF9933;
   clLink = clHotLight; //alias of clHotlight

[Error] file.pas: Constant expression expected
```

and the alternate wording that works:

```
const 
   clHotlight = TColor($00FF9933);
   clLink = clHotLight; //alias of clHotlight
```

Explain.

---

Then consider:

```
const 
   AdministratorGUID: TGUID = '{DE44EEA0-6712-11D4-ADD4-0006295717DA}';
   SuperuserGUID = AdministratorGUID; //alias of AdministratorGUID

[Error] file.pas: Constant expression expected
```

And fix.

**Edit:** Added keyword `const` before declarations; someone didn't believe they were const.

Comment: This sounds to me like you've just cut and pasted a homework assignment, without even bothering to re-word it a bit.

Comment: Not really.  This isn't the sort of thing you'd get a homework assignment on.  Looks to me like he's wandered into a dark corner, and just isn't expressing his question in the best possible way.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: i've not had homework since 1997; assuming 4th year EE project counts as homework.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`clHotlight: TColor = $00FF9933;` is not a constant but a typed constant (=static variable), i.e. the compiler reserves a slot in memory for a TColor which will hold the value `$00FF9933` initially at run time.
Because that value can be changed later (with the Assignable Const option ON), it is not a real constant and cannot be accepted by the compiler in `clLink = clHotLight;`

`clHotlight = TColor($00FF9933);` is strictly the same as `clHotlight = $00FF9933;`
It is a true constant and the compiler will replace `clHotlight` by its value `$00FF9933` wherever it appears in the code. And for `clLink` as well.

Read on this SO question ([**In Delphi 7, why can I assign a value to a const?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934/in-delphi-7-why-can-i-assign-a-value-to-a-const)) and all the good answers there...

**EDIT: about TGUID...**
The problem is that writing `AdministratorGUID: TGUID = '{DE44EEA0-6712-11D4-ADD4-0006295717DA}';` is not proper.
It is using some **compiler magic** to call `StringToGUID` behind the scene, allowing the convenience to express the GUID as a string which they are not by nature. They are records.

So, trying `AdministratorGUID = '{DE44EEA0-6712-11D4-ADD4-0006295717DA}';` will not work. That is not a GUID...

A workaround is to have **a typed constant** and **variables** pointing to the same memory area using the **`absolute`** directive:

```
const
   AdministratorGUID: TGUID = '{DE44EEA0-6712-11D4-ADD4-0006295717DA}';
var
   SuperuserGUID: TGUID absolute AdministratorGUID; //alias of AdministratorGUID
   RootGUID: TGUID absolute AdministratorGUID;      //alias of AdministratorGUID
```

Comment: i see what you, and the other SO question, is saying. But what syntax can i use for the TGUID to make the desired syntax work, e.g. `SuperuserGUID = AdministratorGUID;  RootGUID = AdministratorGUID;' (i.e. where the constant is a record) Or is it not possible in Delphi?

Comment: See my Edit in the answer above.

Answer (score 7):

I tried this code :

```
  const
    CAnswer1 = 42;
    CAnswer2 : Integer = 42;

  var
    LAnswer : Integer;

  begin
    LAnswer := CAnswer1;
    LAnswer := CAnswer2;
  end;
```

and here is the produced code :

```
Project9.dpr.18: LAnswer := CAnswer1;
004101AC C7056C6E41002A00 mov [$00416e6c],$0000002a //<- assign a hard-coded "42" value
Project9.dpr.19: LAnswer := CAnswer2;
004101B6 A1701C4100       mov eax,[$00411c70] //<- fetch a variable's content
004101BB A36C6E4100       mov [$00416e6c],eax //<- assign this content
```

You are right : some constants are more constant than others.
The second constant is actually treated by the compiler as a variable.

Comment: +1 for a good amount of work, and proof-of-concept explanation

Answer (score 5):

```
clHotlight: TColor = $00FF9933; 
          ^
```

Is declaring `clHotlight` as a '*variable*' (well, ok an 'assignable constant' if you've permitted this in compiler options) by means of the `:`.

As you've found, declaring:

```
clHotlight = TColor($00FF9933);
```

Makes no allocation of `clHotlight` until it is specified later.

The same applies to your GUID.

Comment: But i don't have the "Assignable typed constants" option checked! :(

Comment: That doesn't matter, Ian. The option only controls whether they're assignable. It doesn't control the way they're stored.

Answer (score 4):

The problem arises because a typed constant is not, truly, a constant, as has been explained with varying degrees of clarity and success by others.

What hasn't as yet been shown is how to work around the problem (in a large number of cases), though a couple came tantalisingly close to giving up that secret...  :)

In your specific case you can get around the problem by reversing the "aliasing" of the value and the typed constant declaration as follows:

```
const
  clLink = $00FF9933;
  clHotlight: TColor = clLink;
```

**clLink** now provides your true constant and **clHotlight** is the typed constant that has the same value as **clLink**.

For the GUID's the same technique can be used, but you have to bear in mind the normal constant expression used to initialise a typed GUID constant - it doesn't use a record but a simple literal string, so:

```
const
  ID_CONSTANT = '{AA1C8AF2-C290-40AB-9CF5-2888A46E1660}';
  GUID_CONSTANT: TGUID = ID_CONSTANT;
```

**NOTE:** Such GUID constants are perfectly usable in all places where **TGUID**'s are required, e.g. **IsEqualGUID**( tguid, GUID_CONSTANT ) etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, it muddies the GUID declaration because of this inconsistency: ID_CONSTANT is a string and not a TGUID in spite of a declaration which seems the same as the typed const declaration of a TGUID.

Comment: I'm not sure where/why/how it is made "muddy".  I can't off-hand think of an occasion where a true "constant expression" GUID value would be required/useful.  The usual place where this crops up is in a "case" statement, and you couldn't "case" on a GUID value even if it was possible to declare true constant records.

Comment: We use constant GUIDs all the time. The most useful is `NULL_GUID: TGUID = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}';    if IsEqualGUID(key, NULL_GUID) then`. Another example is the one you saw, checking if the thing is a particular predefined user. Another example is declaring a constant COM **clsid** , e.g.: `CLASS_UIRibbonFramework: TGUID = '{926749FA-2615-4987-8845-C33E65F2B957}';`

Comment: I could be wrong but don't think these are examples of cases where a  CONSTANT EXPRESSION is required (the subset of all "constant" declarations that are considered "true" literals).  i.e. you can happily use TYPED constants in such places:  NULL_GUIDSTR = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'; NULL_GUID: TGUID = NULL_GUIDSTR; if IsEqualGUID(key, NULL_GUID) compiles perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Read here [Understanding Typed Constants in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/typedconstant.htm)

Comment: -1 for a link without a summary. Besides, that article doesn't even address the issue being asked about in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The right side of a constant declaration must be a "constant expression", which is defined as "a constant expression is an expression that the compiler can evaluate without executing the program in which it occurs". You can find the whole accepted syntax for constant expression in the language guide.
Note that the language guide explicitly states "Typed constants cannot occur in constant expressions." - and that's why your declarations fails, both clHotlight: TColor = $00FF9933; and AdministratorGUID: TGUID =...; are typed constants.
Also, constant expression cannot include functions calls except those listed in the language guide (i.e. Length(), SizeOf(), and some others) that the compiler is able to compute at compile time.
Rewrite this way:

```
const
  AdminGUID = '{DE44EEA0-6712-11D4-ADD4-0006295717DA}';
  AdministratorGUID: TGUID = AdminGUID;
  SuperuserGUID: TGUID = AdminGUID;
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Delphi evolution. in delphi 1 & 2, you can not assign initial constant value to a global var (ex: var xVar: Integer = 1). The only way you can do that is using const xVar: Integer = 1) and some where in you codes, you can then change it to somethingelse if desired. Until they get rid of this ancient feature, you can not using "const xVar: Integer" construct as a const value.

Cheers
A Pham