# how would i convert this from a constant to a variable array?

Tags: arrays, graph, pascal

```
Uses Graph;
Const Triangle : Array [1..3] Of PointType =
((X: 50; Y: 100),
(X: 100; Y: 100),
(X: 150; Y: 50));
Var Gd, Gm : smallint;
Begin
Gd:=Detect;
InitGraph(Gd, Gm, ''); 
If GraphResult <> grOk Then Halt(1);
SetFillStyle(7,0);
SetColor(14);
FillPoly(SizeOf(Triangle) Div SizeOf(PointType), Triangle);
ReadLn;
CloseGraph;
End.
```

I want to be able to input a value for the triangle so the user can move it arround, but it is a constant so that isn't possible unless there is a way to convert this to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

**For FreePascal:**

Just replace "const" by "var". You can initialize global variables, even complex variables like this one, in this manner, the variable will take this value at the beginning of your program, until you change it.

**For TurboPascal:**

Constant arrays aren't really constants and you can modify them all you want. For instance, you can do:

```
Triangle[1].X := 500;
```

at the beginning of the program and it'll work just fine. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240689/why-pascal-const-arrays-arent-actually-constants) for more details.

Comment: Note this might be mode dependent in FPC since this is basically a Delphi feature.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I took care to try it under FPC with both objfpc, fpc and tp modes. I didn't check how Delphi does it.