# Delphi const string code

Tags: delphi

i get

```
function TForm1.GetArsHedef(): String;
const
 DosyaAdi: String = 'hello';
```

i need

```
function TForm1.GetArsHedef(): String;
const
 DosyaAdi: String = edit1.text+edit2.text;
```

but up the  code not work
who can help

now thanks . etekno

Comment: Why do you need `edit1.text + edit2.text` as a `const`? And what version of Delphi are you using? See  [Delphi assign to `const`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335606/delphi-assign-to-const).

Comment: delphi seattle 10 , I'm doing audio recording program

Comment: Why do you say you "need" that?

Comment: call recording program

Comment: I don't understand what that means, Kaan. What does a recording program have to do with const strings? I've never written any recording program, but I can't imagine how that particular use would need const strings created from input fields. Please expand on your explanation.

Comment: Rob I'm doing call recording program .

Answer (score 3):

Constants have to be constant. They have to be known at compile time. You need a variable.

```
var
  DosyaAdi: String; 
....
DosyaAdi := edit1.text+edit2.text;
```

Comment: Excepted  LIBRARY  but received an identifier

Comment: That's another problem. You have displayed an uncanny ability to produce non sequiteurs.

Comment: I do not know how
I have chosen you want to print the values ​​on an editor , but it does not allow const factor
(edit1.text+edit2.text) I want to do as

Comment: Are you having difficulty understand what the word "constant" means in this context? The key part of my answer is: *they have to be known at compile time*. Does that make sense to you? Have you read anything that anyone has written?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a variable, and in your function you won't even need to declare one. Delphi automatically declares the variable `Result` in a function and makes it the proper type to be returned.

```
function TForm1.GetArsHedef(): String;
begin
  Result := Edit1.Text + Edit2.Text;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you wish to do. Constants are converted to their actual values at compile-time, and are not dynamic. Especially since this constant is local to a procedure, just use a variable instead. The word "constant" itself explains that it's intended to be the same value "constantly".

In any case, you cannot define or declare local variables or constants while setting their default values to another variable. To read the contents of these edit controls, it must be code explicitly written in the implementation to assign it.

Comment: Although, you might want to check this out: [Delphi assign to `const`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335606/delphi-assign-to-const).

Comment: I think the op wants the value assigned to `DosyaAdi` to persist when re-entering the function. Some like assignable constants.

Comment: @lurker Indeed, assigning to a constant is technically possible, but OP wishes to define a constant with a direct reference to a control. I personally don't see any reason to want to assign to a constant when you could use a variable instead. It's like buying a car just to use it as a snow sled.

Comment: @JerryDodge you are probably right. The OP's question is a bit terse, though, so it's hard to tell what they really need.

Comment: Well, an expression with __variables__ in it is not a __constant__ expression and you need the former to initialize a constant.